# Megamenu is loading before logo in visual composer wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I am using wordpress and visual composer plugin in my website. I have used megamenu in my visual composer which is getting loaded through a shortcode for listing subcategories. The problem is that in my visual composer, I have put the logo first, then navbar and then cart but the menubar is being loaded first in the html code of the page. Also there is a small bar for cart link which I have put above the logo but it is being loaded below logo. I think the position element of menubar is taking it to the top but I don't know the fix. There is some css hack in this. The link of live website is [here.](http://newsite.cealinetweezers.com/) Anyone can please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo and menu loaded fine, but your page size is huge which is most likely the root of your issues with page speed, 8779 KB; you need to optimise your images and concatenate your js and css. I use [Autoptimize plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) for this.

Using the plugin I set it to concatenate and minify css and js, and sometimes html but this last bit sometimes breaks other things like plugins that us js, so do this last and test.

As an example it took 8-10 seconds for your slider images and the slider to load on the home page, and this can be greatly improved with better asset optimisation.